# How to test nested Object in with Spring MockMVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a controller with a POST method to test. The method will post a book to the reader's reading list. It will grab the currently authenticated user as the reader. The `Book` Class has a field that is a `Reader` type. The following code uses `contains(samePropertyValuesAs(expectedBook))`, but the `reader` instance location is different from the `expectedReader` I created obviously.

What is the correct way to test such nested Object in MockMVC?

```
@Test
@WithUserDetails("z")
public void addBookShouldShowTheBookInReadingList() throws Exception {

    final String bookTitle = "BOOK A";
    final String bookAuthor = "JK";
    final String isbn = "1234567890";
    final String description = "Yet another book.";

    mockMvc.perform(post("/readingList")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
            .param("title", bookTitle)
            .param("author", bookAuthor)
            .param("isbn", isbn)
            .param("description", description)
            .with(csrf()))
        .andExpect(status().is3xxRedirection())
        .andExpect(header().string("Location", "/readingList"));


    Reader expectedReader = new Reader();
    expectedReader.setUsername("z");
    expectedReader.setPassword("test");
    expectedReader.setFullName("Z H");

    Book expectedBook = new Book();
    expectedBook.setId(1L);
    expectedBook.setTitle(bookTitle);
    expectedBook.setAuthor(bookAuthor);
    expectedBook.setIsbn(isbn);
    expectedBook.setDescription(description);
    expectedBook.setReader(expectedReader);

    mockMvc.perform(get("/readingList"))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(model().attributeExists("books"))
        .andExpect(model().attribute("books", hasSize(1)))
        .andExpect(model().attribute("books", contains(samePropertyValuesAs(expectedBook))));

}
```

Update - additional POST signature.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/readingList")
public class ReadingListController {

    private ReadingListService readingListService;
    private VersionConfig versionConfig;

    @Autowired
    public ReadingListController(final ReadingListService readingListService,
                                 final VersionConfig versionConfig) {
        this.readingListService = readingListService;
        this.versionConfig = versionConfig;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String readersBooks(Reader reader, Model model) {
        readingListService.findByReader(reader)
            .ifPresent(books -> {
                model.addAttribute("books", books);
                model.addAttribute("reader", reader);
                model.addAttribute("releaseId", versionConfig.getReleaseId());
            });

        return "readingList";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addToReadingList(Reader reader, Book book) {
        book.setReader(reader);
        readingListService.save(book);
        return "redirect:/readingList";
    }
}
```

Comment: show your POST method signature and are you trying to write unit tests or integration tests?

Comment: @SabirKhan - please see updated post. It is a unit test just to test the `addToReadingList` method which is a `POST` request method in the Controller.

Comment: @ZhenyangHua don't update your question with the answer. Create a new answer with the solution using `hasToString()`.

Answer (score 0):

So there is a `hasToString()` matcher could be used in hamcrast to get this done.

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/readingList"))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(model().attributeExists("books"))
        .andExpect(model().attribute("books", hasSize(1)))
        .andExpect(model().attribute("books", contains(hasToString(expectedBook.toString()))));
```